Induced matrix norm, for strange vector norm
I have the following vector norm $||x|| = max[|x_2|,|x_1|+\frac{1}{2} |x_2|], x \in R^2$.How can I compute its induced matrix norm? I have tried several p-norms, but the problem is that I have $|x_1| + \frac{1}{2} |x_2|$ instead of $|x_1 + \frac{1}{2} x_2|$

Do you know how to find the induced matrix norm for the standard vector norm?

Yes, for standard euclidean norm I use spectral norm

But,I guess in my case this strategy wouldn't work,isn't it?
